# Image conversion from Gray to RGB in matlab- showing negative image

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, grayscale, matlab-compiler

The following is the code I used to convert a gray scale compressed image into RGB in MATLAB. But the output image is somewhat of negative image type.
can anyone please tell if there is any other way to get a better rgb image or if there are any mistakes in the code?
[OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZkQf.jpg)

```
cmap = turbo(256); % Or whatever one you want.
rgbImage = ind2rgb(img2, cmap); % Convert gray scale image into an RGB image
```

Comment: what do you mean "negative image type" ? Can you show us the code that loads `img2` and the image itself too? You may be having issues with image types I guess. `img2` has to be an indexed image for this to work. for example, if you do this with the MATLAB example image `[X,cmap] = imread('corn.tif');`, it works as expected, there are no negative values in the image.

Comment: Do you mean that the result is like the negative of an image? But that makes sense, you are just applying the turbo colormap. An indexed image needs to come with a colormap. You really need to show us your real problem, not this example

Comment: From what you show, it seem to me that your code works and that this is indeed the output you should have. You could always add `flipud(cmap);` to flip your colormap around and get the "negative" of what you have here. Apart from that, I'd say, play with colormaps until you have the result you want